# How to repack multiple zip files

Tags: linux, compression, zip

I have multiple zip files in a main directory that need to be repacked recursively. These files have spaces, apostrophes, underscores, etc.

`advzip` doesn't work as it complains about an unsupported compression method (a reason they need to be repacked). All these files unzip, they just need to be rezipped/packed with some automation as there are thousands.

Files were originally created under Windows using MP3+G Toolz for a karaoke library.

OS: Linux Mint 18
Script Writing: Novice

```bash
for file in *.zip
do
 unzip -j "$file"
 rm -f "$file"
 zip -mq "$file" *.mp3 *.cdg *.MP3 *.CDG *.Mp3 *.Cdg
 rm -f *.mp3 *.cdg *.MP3 *.CDG *.Mp3 *.Cdg
done
```

Above is what I'm looking for, for the most par. But since I'm not good with scripts I am unsure how to make it for all zip's in sub-directories too. Example of a filename:

```
SC0000-01 - Someone - Something.zip
```

files in the zip are

```
SC0000-01 - Someone - Something.cdg
SC0000-01 - Someone - Something.mp3
```

Comment: How were the files created? You would need to do something like `find DirPath -name "NameMask" | while read -r z; do UnzipProgram Options "$z"; advzip Options "$z"; done`. Without knowing your distribution or your original compression program, I cannot give more detail. Alternatively, forget about `advzip` and stick with your original compression program (the `advzip` manual page warns of incompatibilities).

Answer (score 0):

when mentioning advzip i am assuming you use Linux. Here you can write a simple script that loop each file

```
for f in *; 
 do; 
 unzip $f; 
done
```

hope this helps, otherwise it would be advised to provide some more detail.

Comment: Something similar, I've updated my post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've just made this more complicated than it needs to be:

```bash
find . -name "*.zip" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
 unzip -j "$file"
 rm -f "$file"
 zip -mq "$file" *.mp3 *.cdg *.MP3 *.CDG *.Mp3 *.Cdg
 rm -f *.mp3 *.cdg *.MP3 *.CDG *.Mp3 *.Cdg
done
```